# Creating v10 database at Azure

Tags: azure

I'm wondering if I can create a v10 database on Azure (SQL Database) instead of v12.

*I doesn't work it with virtual machine.

Currently my company using an accounting software which is now using v10 database. after I restore the database to azure, there's some connection problem in the accounting software: it can connect to the database, but has some query running in the accounting software that doesn't support v12.

> Unknown Sql Exception (Number=40515, Message=Reference to database and/or server name in 'master.dbo.sysdatabases' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.)
>
> Exception class type: Exception
>   Stack Trace:
>      at BCE.Data.DataError.HandleSqlException(SqlException ex)
>      at BCE.Data.DBSetting.ExecuteScalar(String cmdText, Object[] parameters)
>      at BCE.AutoCount.LicenseControl.NetworkController.NetworkContollerSql.IsDbExist()
>      at BCE.AutoCount.LicenseControl.NetworkController.Initialize()
>      at BCE.AutoCount.LicenseControl.NetworkController.Create(DBSetting dbSetting)
>      at BCE.AutoCount.MainEntry.Startup.LoginToNetworkController(DBSetting dbSetting, Boolean performLogin)
>      at BCE.AutoCount.MainEntry.Startup.Login(DBSetting dbSetting, String userID, String password, StartupLicenseControlType slcType, String dgServerName, Int32 dgServerPort, StartupPlugInOption loadPlugInOption, Boolean enableConcurrentNetworkUserChecking, Boolean isAccountantLicense, Boolean checkDongleLicense)
>      at BCE.AutoCount.MainEntry.Startup.A2006StandardStartup(String dmfPath, Boolean allowUpgradeMode)
>      at BCE.AutoCount.MainEntry.Startup.Start(String dmfPath, Boolean allowUpgradeMode)
>   at BCE.AutoCount.A2006.Main(String[] args)

The following are the loaded assemblies:

```
mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
Accounting, Version=1.8.20.136, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
BCE.AutoCount.MainEntry, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
BCE.Utils.UI, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
BCE.Utils, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
BCE.AutoCount.CommonAccounting, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
BCE.AutoCount, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
DevExpress.Utils.v13.1, Version=13.1.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a
System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Numerics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
BCE.AutoCount.GL, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
DevExpress.XtraReports.v13.1, Version=13.1.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a
DevExpress.XtraReports.v13.1.Extensions, Version=13.1.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a
DevExpress.XtraBars.v13.1, Version=13.1.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a
BCE.AutoCount.GST, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
BCE.AutoCount.ARAP, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
BCE.AutoCount.Manufacturing, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
BCE.AutoCount.Stock, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
BCE.AutoCount.Invoicing, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
BCE.AutoCount.Invoicing.Sales, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
BCE.AutoCount.Invoicing.Purchase, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
BCE.AutoCount.StockMaint, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
BCE.AutoCount.GeneralMaint, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
BCE.AutoCount.Tools, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
DevExpress.Data.v13.1, Version=13.1.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a
DevExpress.XtraEditors.v13.1, Version=13.1.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a
DevExpress.BonusSkins.v13.1, Version=13.1.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a
DevExpress.XtraGrid.v13.1, Version=13.1.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a
System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
BCE.AutoCount.MainEntry.XmlSerializers, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
DevExpress.XtraVerticalGrid.v13.1, Version=13.1.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a
DevExpress.XtraTreeList.v13.1, Version=13.1.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a
System.Transactions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
BCE.AutoCount.ManageAccountBook, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
BCE.AutoCount.BusinessFlow, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
```

Comment: You never mentioned if you're working with a VM or with SQL Database Service. If the former, install whatever you want. If the latter, you're limited to what the service offers.

Comment: I'm working with the SQL Database Service, doesn't related to any VM

Answer (score 0):

You can create any version you like in a VM (as a workaround) as for the actual Azure SQL, you can uncheck v12 during deployment, it should deploy version 11. Not sure if that help.
I'm pretty sure no version 10.